# PHP slice array into parts

Tags: php, arrays, slice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php split array into smaller even arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861530/php-split-array-into-smaller-even-arrays)

How can I slice an array into multiple parts ? Lets say I have this array:

`$arr = range(1, 15);`

How can I end up with this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
       ............
)
```

What I've tried so far :

```
$parts = 3;
$slices = array();

for($i=0; $i<($parts * $parts); $i=$i+$parts){
  $sliced = array_slice($arr, $i, (count($arr) / $parts));
  array_push($slices, $sliced);
}
```

It seems to be working fine  **only with arrays under 10 elements**  that makes me confused about why and how that code works really, it doesn't seem static to me as well.. Is there any other way to do it or a fix for the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) instead of writing your own:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);
```