# How to extract array?

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have a simple Array:

```
Array (
        [1] => 36
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 16
        [4] => 49
        [5] => 17
        [6] => 19
        [7] => 13
        [8] => 18
        [9] => 34
        [10] => 22
        [11] => 11
        [12] => 92
        [13] => 14
        [14] => 12
        [15] => 20
        [16] => 95
        [17] => 23
        [18] => 15
    )
```

I want to convert to arrays as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 49
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 18
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34
            [1] => 22
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 92
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 12
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 95
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 15
        )

)
```

How can I ? Give me some clues. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you'll tag the question as `php`

Comment: possible duplicate of [php split array into smaller even arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861530/php-split-array-into-smaller-even-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to achieve this:

```
$new_array_format = array_chunk($original_array, 2);
```

Comment: As a newbie you should learn how to research your own problems, and read documentation.